# Converting base 2 to base 16

Tags: math, logic, converters

I have seen many people get confused about how to convert base 2 to base 16 directly. In this tutorial I will explain how to convert a Binary number to a Hexadecimal number in 5 easy steps.

Comment: StackOverflow is a place to ask questions, not to post tutorials.

Comment: Sorry guys, just tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

1) When you have a number in base 2, all digits must be either 0 or 1. If you have a digit(s) that isn't  0 or 1, your number is not in base 2 (Binary) and this tutorial won't be of use for you.

2) Make sure the length of you number is divisible by 4 (4,8,12,16 etc...). In this tutorial I will use 10001111011 in base 2 as the base number. Notice there there are only 11 digits. to make it divisible by 4 we will add a 0 to the left side of the number and check if the length is divisible by 4, keep on adding 0's until it is divisible.

3) Part your base 2 number into groups of four. In our case, 010001111011 will be 0100  0111  1011.

4) Now use the following table to convert each group of four digits to its matching value in base 16:

0000 = 0

0001 = 1

0010 = 2

0011 = 3

0100 = 4

0101 = 5

0110 = 6

0111 = 7

1000 = 8

1001 = 9

1010 = A

1011 = B

1100 = C

1101 = D

1110 = E

1111 = F

5) As a reminder, out number was 0100 0111 1011. Then 0100=4, 0111=7, 1011=B. Therefore. 010001111011 in base 2 is 47B in base 16(hexadecimal).